# Can I set the name of the generated IPA file?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a user-defined attribute that I set for `CFBundleName`:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(APP_DISPLAY_NAME)</string>
```

`APP_DISPLAY_NAME == THIS IS MY APP` <-- it is the app name that I can see on my iPhone after I installed the app,

The problem is that also the IPA file name will be `THIS IS MY APP.ipa`. What is the problem with all the spaces while working with this file in the pipeline?

Is there a way to version this as `my_app_prod_1_2_1` or `my_app_dev_1_2_1` for the name of the file produced?

Comment: What string do you want to appear for the file?

Comment: If it would not contain spaces that would be a start. If I could set the IPA file based on the scheme I use for the build that is also would be cool, maybe the version of the app...

So something like: `my_app_prod_1_2_1` or `my_app_dev_1_2_1`

Comment: Nice - my initial instinct was to name it “bad_pipeline”

Answer (score 0):

In your app's Build Settings, change the `PRODUCT_NAME`.